# Getting .done() of request from another function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have a form where I load the items of the select menu with ajax. But there is also an option which fills in all selects with the `change()` function. But since it needs to wait for the ajax request to be done I need to set an interval which would be different each time so I cannot use it that way.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $("#car_brand").val(vehicle.brand).change();
}, 100);
```

So this changes the value of `#car_brand` and car_brand loads all the options from the database when it gets changed. So if I don't set another interval it tries to change it without the new options being loaded. Is there a way to use the `.done()` of the ajax request here?

Ajax request

```
function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "inc/ajax/form_rest.php",
        data: { q:str, prevvalue:prevvalue, value:value, vehicletype:vehicletype },
        success: function(html) {
                    $('#'+id).html(html);
                }
        })
        .done(function(){
            $("#"+id).removeAttr("disabled");
        });
}
```

Whole change function

```
function returnVehicleByValue(vehicleValue, vozila){
    $.get("inc/ajax/selectMojaVozila.php", 
        {vehicleValue:vehicleValue},
        function(html){
            var vehicle = html;
            //Select Moja Vozila
                $("#"+vozila+"_year").val(vehicle.Year).change()
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#"+vozila+"_brand").val(vehicle.Marke_vozila).change();
                }, 100);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#"+vozila+"_model").val(vehicle.Model_vozila).change();
                }, 350);

                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#"+vozila+"_type").val(vehicle.Tip_vozila).change();
                }, 500);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#"+vozila+"_uitvoering").val(vehicle.izvedba_vozila).change();
                }, 700);
        }, 'json'
    );
}
```

Comment: So each select loads its options via ajax? Could you have the previous one trigger the next one? so in the _year ajax done it triggers _brand's change? and in the _brand ajax it triggers the _model change?

Comment: Hmm I think it wouldn't work that way because I need to use the updateField function for other purposes too. But maybe I could put another parameter inside updateField in the done() function and when it is set it changes the value of the next select. And put the function updateField inside returnVehicleByValue... Just no idea yet how exactly I am going to do it but I am going to try

Comment: I don't understand why you need all these arbitrary timeouts? Why can't you trigger all the change events at once?

Comment: Because I load them with ajax and I can't select them before they are loaded. So I need to make it wait till they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm following your question correctly, you could use the `complete` handler for the ajax method:

```
function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "inc/ajax/form_rest.php",
        data: { q:str, prevvalue:prevvalue, value:value, vehicletype:vehicletype },
        success: function(html) {
                    $('#'+id).html(html);
                },
        complete: function() {
             $("#car_brand").val(vehicle.brand).change();
             //all your code

        }
        })
        .done(function(){
            $("#"+id).removeAttr("disabled");
        });
}
```

The complete callback fires after `success` and `error` callbacks.
See documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Nice to keep in mind but it didn't quite work the way I wanted. I gave up on it and did it another way instead. Thanks anyway!